# JavaScript : pause function to get value by event listener

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScrip and I am making a card game that has three AI players and the user. I want to call startGame() function which checks for the turn then if its AI turn call aiPlay() and if it human turn get card index by clicking on its image. **the problem is I can't figure out how to make the function wait for the player to click on a card then continue. here is my code**

```
function starGame() {
    for (round; round <= 13; round++) {
        let x = turnOrder(turn);
        for (z = 0; z < 4; z++) {

            if (x[z] == 0) {

                // Here I want the player to click on a card and get card index 
                // Cards have on click event listener like card.onclick=playCard;

                } else {
                aiPlay(turn,card);
            }

            turn++;
            if (turn > 3) { turn = 0; }
        }

        turn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

    }

}
```

Comment: Get familiar with promises and then use `async`/`await` syntax

Comment: thank you. I'll do

Comment: Since you are new to javascript, you should use global variables to keep track of the state (i.e. turn, round etc.). You need to modify your function such that it is called whenever the users makes a move. So you can start by waiting for the user, when the user makes a move the function is called, it updates the global variables, ai makes a move and then the function exits. This is repeated for each move until a move/loose condition is met.

Comment: @BurhanB being new to a language is not an excuse for bad practices. Don't use global variables.

Comment: I found a solution using async/await. it's not that hard